# How to create a backup in Artifactory of a part of a repository?

Tags: artifactory

We can create backups of whole repositories in Aritfactory.
One of the repo's is really too big. We want backup parts of it. Is it possible to create a backup of a part of a repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclusion is possible only at the repository level. So, breaking up the large repo into smaller repos might be the only option available.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Artifactory to create a Backup of a part of a repository.

In your case, the best practice is to have multiple repositories and not a too big repository.

For example, you can have a local and a remote repository by technology and functional domain or project.